# SQL Server 2005 update only updates one instance

Tags: sql-server

I am currently in the process of performing updates on a SQL Server. Our SQL Server contains two databases, lets call them `\\smyqlserver\$database1` and `\\mysqlserver\$database2`.

I perform the first hotfix and the installer ends reporting successful installation.  However, upon attemping the next hotfix in the sequence, it fails due to `\\mysqlserver\$database1` possessing the correct version (4211) while reporting that `\\mysqlserver\$database2` is still at the initial version (4035)

Wouldn't the hotfix update both instances at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, they typically only do one instance at a time.  There are definitely times when you *wouldn't* want to do all instances at once.  What hotfix are you installing?

Comment: Specifically, KB961930.

Answer (score 0):

Each service pack and hotfix need to be applied to each instance independently of each other.